# ckeditor 4 accessing focusmanager with dynamically created editor insantces

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, ckeditor, wysiwyg

i currently have 1 editor that will always be on the page when it loads, the page has a feature to add multiple editors by clicking a add button.

my code works on the first editor only that is loaded with the page, how can i adapt this to work on all the editors on the page, even if dynamically created after the page has been loaded? (the dynamically created editors)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function(instance){
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[instance];
        if (editor) {
            editor.on( 'focus', function( e ) {
                $('.hint').show();
            });
            editor.on( 'blur', function( e ) {
                $('.hint').hide();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**eidt 1** - fullcode minus html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').each(function(i) {
        var editorId = $(this).attr('id');
        if(editorId != 'master'){
            if( $(this).hasClass('main') ){
                ckeditor_simple_toolbar(editorId);
            }
            if( $(this).hasClass('extras') ){
                ckeditor_advanced_toolbar(editorId);
            }
        }
    });

    $.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function(instance){
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[instance];
        if (editor) {
            editor.on( 'focus', function( e ) {
                $('.hint').show();
            });
            editor.on( 'blur', function( e ) {
                $('.hint').hide();
            });
        }
    });

    $('.add_extra').live('click',function(){
        ckeditor_advanced_toolbar(this.id);
    });
});


function ckeditor_simple_toolbar(textA_id){
    CKEDITOR.replace(textA_id,{
        tabSpaces           : 4
    });
}

function ckeditor_advanced_toolbar(textA_id){
    CKEDITOR.replace(textA_id,{
        emailProtection     : 'encode',
        tabSpaces           : 4,
        extraPlugins        : 'autogrow',
        height              : 100,
        autoGrow_minHeight  : 100,
        autoGrow_maxHeight  : 400,
        removePlugins       : 'resize',
        toolbarLocation     : 'bottom',
    });
}
```

**edit 2**
here is a test setup of what is happening, the focus and blur aren't working on the dynamically added editors

http://elhalawa.net/editor/index.html

Comment: Provide the code in relation to the other editors.

Comment: theres no html it just basic textarea's
<textarea name="main" id="main" class="main"></textarea>

Comment: CKEDITOR.instances has to be the data or id of the editor, so that will help to solve the other editors so it was needed that the we need to find how the other editors are identified or is CKEDITOR same for all editors?

Comment: each editor has a unique id, i updated with a link to a test page

Comment: Here on the test page when I keep clicking on 'add another', many editors get loaded. So now is the problem only on focus and blur?

Comment: well i have other functions i need to run, however i run them the same way as focus and blur. how do i get focus and blur to work with those editors added by the button?

Comment: When you click on the text field, a red box shows hint test, and if you click elsewhere it hides. So it does those functions as well.

Comment: correct, but only for the first editor, i need that to happen for all the editors, even for the ones that are made when the button is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just added the on instanceReady code and it worked great

```
CKEDITOR.replace(textA_id,{
    emailProtection     : 'encode',
    tabSpaces           : 4,
    extraPlugins        : 'autogrow',
    height              : 100,
    autoGrow_minHeight  : 100,
    autoGrow_maxHeight  : 400,
    removePlugins       : 'resize',
    toolbarLocation     : 'bottom',

}).on("instanceReady", function (e) {
    this.on("focus", function () {

    });

    this.on("blur", function () {

    });

    this.on( 'change', function() {

    });
});
```